# Wait till process is no longer running OR until timeout has passed, whichever happens first

Tags: c#, .net, timeout

I want to  kill a process running on the machine using taskkill if they're  still running after X seconds (a windows service was stopped but it takes time for processes to dissapear)
What's the most correct way to accomplish the above in C# (.net 2.0 or possibly 3.0)?

I've utility method for verifying whether a process is still running, given the process name  (using `Process.GetProcesses()`). 
(As the process is not spawned by my code, I can't use WaitTillExit to know when it's no longer running)

PS: the process runs on a remote machine

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In fact, you can use Process.WaitForExit().

Simply get the process to wait for via

```
Process p = Process.GetProcessById(iYourID);
```

And then call

```
if(!p.WaitForExit(iYourInterval))
{ 
    p.Kill();
}
```

You can also get processes via their name by

```
Process.GetProcessesByName(strYourProcessName);
```

Comment: Cool! Now, if I can this to work on remote machine, this is just what needed (since I need to kill a whole bunch of processes with the same exe name) 
Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget `Kill()` executes asynchronously and doesn't kill any child processes (see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks)). If you'd like to wait for the process to actually be killed, follow up with a `p.WaitForExit()`.

Answer (score 13):

You could call [`Process.WaitForExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56.aspx), passing the appropriate timeout. This way you won't need to use your own check to see whether the process is still running.

Comment: I'm not sure how this achieves "killing" the process if it's till running after  timeout has passed, though...

Comment: I thought you were going to use taskkill?

Comment: `WaitForExit` returns `false` if the process is still running after the timeout; use this to determine whether to kill it

Comment: Arrggh, now realized the question is not phrased correctly. Will edit now, please view again.

Answer (score 12):

```
Process p = ...

bool exited = p.WaitForExit(10000); // 10 seconds timeout
```