# Time limit for process

Tags: c#, .net, process

Is it possible to set time limit for process? I realize that this can be done using multithreading. For instance I could use one thread that executes the process and an other thread that kills it after the some amount of time, but isn't there a more simple solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because such a solution would not know exactly how to stop the process after the time limit has elapsed. Killing the process outright is potentially dangerous stuff, so in the general case the process needs to cooperate for a graceful shutdown to be achieved.

It's really not that difficult to set up a timer and have your main loop check for a condition that signifies the timer has elapsed.

Comment: If we're talking `Process` and not `Thread`, he [can do like this.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3522035/39106)

Comment: I mean killing not process of the executable itself but killing another program process if this process has been running more than one second for example.

Comment: @FilipEkberg: I don't think the OP meant a system process.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, I'm not sure.

Comment: @seeker: Then Filip's link is what you want, **although** outright killing a process is potentially dangerous as I mention. Of course you will need some way of identifying the target process.

Comment: @seeker: Your terminology confused people. You are talking about "program process". Is this the process of another program? Or is this a "process" in YOUR program, i.e. an operation inside your own program?

Comment: My program execute another program using Create method of system.diagnostic.process class. And I want to have this process after some amount of time.

Comment: @seeker: `Process.Start` gives you back a value that you can immediately call `WaitForExit` on as that other answer suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You could spawn the process, wait a certain amount of time, and then kill it.

```
var proc = Process.Start("myproc.exe");
bool graceful = proc.WaitForExit(10000);  //Wait 10 secs.
if (!graceful)
{
    proc.Kill();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the thread that is executing can periodically check itself and exit gracefully, no. In most cases you cannot trust an executing thread to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you start the process you can as well schedule it with schtasks /create.

That will give you what you need almost for free (almost because your startup process is a little bit more complex, there are no free lunches)

```
SCHTASKS /Create /SC DAILY /TN gaming /TR c:\freecell /ST 12:00  /ET 14:00 /K
```

[Knowledgebase article on schtasks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814596)